# How can I nest v-fors inside my component file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have read the VueJS tutorials but I still cannot come up with a solution to this.

I have a list of lists, and I want to display them using accordions (which is a component from vue-strap, tested to be working properly several times before).

So having a list such as:

```
'myList': [
  ['el 1', 'el 2', 'el 3'], ['el 1', 'el 2'], ['el another']
]
```

I would expect the following visualization:

List 1:

- el 1
- el 2
- el 3

List 2:

- el 1
- el 2

List 3:

- el another

But VueJS is not rendering this component...!

The code is as follows:

```
<template>
  <accordion id="rabo" :one-at-atime="true">
    <template v-for="list in myLists">
      <panel header="List #{{ $index }}" :is-open="true">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="el in list">
            {{el}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </panel>
    </template>
  </accordion>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import { accordion, panel } from 'vue-strap'

  module.exports = {
    components: {
      'accordion': accordion,
      'panel': panel
    }
  }

  new Vue({
    el: '#rabo',
    data: {
      'myLists': [['el 1', 'el 2', 'el 3'],['el 1','el 2'],['el another']]
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: A `<template>` tag inside another `<template>` tag just doesn't look right to me. You should define a second component, then use that component inside your first template. However, for you example, you may just want to remove that second `<template>` tag and replace with another element, a div for ex. Also, are you using Vueify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

1. create the Vue instance to a separate file
2. put the `myLists` array into the `data` of component
3. bind the `header` prop

**MyAccordion.vue**

```
<template>
  <accordion :one-at-atime="true">
    <template v-for="list in myLists">
      <panel :header="`List #${$index}`" :is-open="true">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="el in list">
            {{el}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </panel>
    </template>
  </accordion>
</template>

<script>
  import { accordion, panel } from 'vue-strap'

  export default {
    components: {
      accordion, panel
    },

    data () {
      return {
        myLists: [
          ['el 1', 'el 2', 'el 3'],
          ['el 1', 'el 2'],
          ['el another']
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Vue instance**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyAccordion from './MyAccordion.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  components: { MyAccordion }
})
```

http://www.webpackbin.com/VyPHjF_V-

Comment: Amazing!

Can you just tell me what is wrong with the $index variable? VueJS is not processing it, it shows ${$index} in the webpage. I've tried all combinations I can remember of ${{$index}}, ${{index}}, ${index}, etc...

Thanks!